# Extracting only hour out of time stamp data. Putting it into a linear regression model. Do i need to one-hot encode?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, time-series

I made a new feature called 'Hour' where I extracted only the hour from the timestamp data.

```
df['hour'] = df.index.hour
df.hour.head(10)

Sample : 
Timestamp
2018-10-01 00:00:00    0
2018-10-01 00:15:00    0
2018-10-01 00:30:00    0
2018-10-01 00:45:00    0
2018-10-01 01:00:00    1
2018-10-01 01:15:00    1
2018-10-01 01:30:00    1
2018-10-01 01:45:00    1
2018-10-01 02:00:00    2
2018-10-01 02:15:00    2
Name: hour, dtype: int64
```

When I'm loading this as a feature into my linear regression model, do I need to one-hot encode it?

Thoughts in my mind:

Even though they are categorical, isn't 9(9am) greater than 8(8am)?
23(11pm) is greater than 0(12am) --- not true.

So I'm guessing I do need to hot encode. 
What are the clear rules of when I should and should not hot encode?

Comment: What is "hot encoding"?

Comment: @martineau - hi. *one-hot encoding. is when you take categorical variables and make each category into a binary column with true false values. 
So in this case. when the feature called hour is one-hot encoded. it results in 24 new features.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe there should be a linear relationship between the hours and your output you can add it as a single feature. However in your case it doesn't look like there will be any such relationship. So you can add the hour column as dummy variable or one hot encoding. When using one hot encoding You should set `fit_intercept=False` the dummy variable trap as described in [here](https://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html).